# How to customize Angular Material Card for mobile

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

So I have the following desktop layout (which I am completely satisfied with):

[image: Desktop]

This is my attempt to make it mobile:

[image: Mobile]

I like the horizontal scroll here, but I feel that the cards are too thin; I would like to stretch my card to be more box-like (square). Ideally, the card is big enough to fill the gap between the header and the footer without causing

HTML:

```
<div class="page-content">
      <div class="card-deck" fxLayout.xs="row" style="overflow: scroll; height:100%">

        <md-card style="width:10rem;" *ngFor="let make of filteredMakes" (click)="goToModels(make.niceName)"
                 class="page-card mat-card">
          <img md-card-image=""  src="assets/img/gallery/brands/256/{{make.name}}.png" class="mat-card-image" />
          <md-card-subtitle  class="mat-card-title text-center">{{ make.name }}</md-card-subtitle>
        </md-card>
    </div>

</div>
```

I've tried many css tricks and tried using flexbox, but there must be something I'm missing (media queries perhaps, and how to override them).

How can I make the following styles apply ONLY to mobile?

```
min-height: 375px;min-width: 278px;
```

If anyone has any direction on how to accomplish this design, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You definitely need to be using some media queries here, but you mention overriding them? Are you currently using a framework?

Comment: @JesseEarley yes, I am using Angular4 with Angular Material 2.0.0-b2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get a different style for mobile, we do this:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  md-card {
    min-width:17rem;
  }
}
```